# Word Break Problem with no matching word in Dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the word break problem. But some input cases are not giving result.

**Code**

```
def wordBreak(words, word, out=''):
 
    # if the end of the string is reached,
    # print the output string
    if not word:
        print(out)
        return
 
    for i in range(1, len(word) + 1):
        # consider all prefixes of the current string
        prefix = word[:i]
        
 
        # if the prefix is present in the dictionary, add it to the
        # output string and recur for the remaining string
        if prefix in words:
            wordBreak(words, word[i:], out + ' ' + prefix)
        

 
 
# Word Break Problem Implementation
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    # List of strings to represent a dictionary
    words = [
        'self', 'th', 'is', 'famous', 'Word', 'break', 'b', 'r',
        'e', 'a', 'k', 'br', 'bre', 'brea', 'ak', 'problem'
    ]
 
    # input string
    word = 'Wordbreakproblem'
 
    wordBreak(words, word)
```

**Present Output**

```
 Word b r e a k problem
 Word b r e ak problem
 Word br e a k problem
 Word br e ak problem
 Word bre a k problem
 Word bre ak problem
 Word brea k problem
 Word break problem
```

If `word = 'sWordbreakproblem'`, then the code is not giving any output. Here in this word, `s` at the beginning of the word, the output has to be `sWordbreakproblem`
and if `s` is at the end of the word then the output has to be like

```
 Word b r e a k problem s
 Word b r e ak problem s
 Word br e a k problem s
 Word br e ak problem s
 Word bre a k problem s
 Word bre ak problem s
 Word brea k problem s
 Word break problem s
```

If s is at the middle of the word like `Wordbreaksproblem`

```
 Word b r e a k sproblem 
 Word b r e ak sproblem 
 Word br e a k sproblem 
 Word br e ak sproblem 
 Word bre a k sproblem 
 Word bre ak sproblem 
 Word brea k sproblem 
 Word break sproblem
```

Comment: What is "the word break problem"?

Comment: @Pychopath Given an input string and a dictionary of words, this has to find out if the input string can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of dictionary words.

Comment: Then your empty output is correct. Because 'sWordhllobreakproblem' can't be segmented like that. Also, not clear why you show several segmentations if the job is to just find out **if** it can be done. Correct result is a single boolean.

Comment: @Pychopath There was a mistake in the example word given. Corrected that now

Comment: I didn't even notice that 'hllo' in there. I'm talking about that 's' at the start. Because of that, 'sWordbreakproblem' is still not segmentable with that dictionary of words. And you're still showing multiple segmentations instead of one boolean value.

Comment: @Pychopath if input word is sWordbreakproblem the output has to be sWordbreakproblem itself. No break up is possible. If s is at the end or at the middle then only break up is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is considerably harder than the original word break problem. It can still be solved in linear time, but using automata theory. However, luckily enough, automata theory translates very well to regular expressions (even though Python's implementation is not based on automata theory, and therefore slower):

```py
import re

def word_break(word, dictionary):
  pattern = "(" + "|".join("(%s)" % word for word in dictionary) + ")"
  reobj = re.compile(pattern)
  i = 0
  for match in reobj.finditer(word):
    if match.start() != i:
      print(word[i:match.start()], end=" ")
    print(match.group(), end=" ")
    i = match.end()
  print(word[i:])
```

This has a **linear complexity** (contrary to the other approaches considered so far in this post).
And, also

```
>>> word_break(
...    "sWordhllobreakproblem",
...     [
...        'self', 'th', 'is', 'famous', 'Word', 'break', 'b', 'r',
...        'e', 'a', 'k', 'br', 'bre', 'brea', 'ak', 'problem'
...     ]
... )
...
s Word hllo break problem
>>>
```

---

#### Edit

I had completely missed the point of the original question. So, here is the working solution.
At least, this solution does the following job: it break the given word in all the possible way with words of the dictionary, except for the last word which may not belong to the dictionary, if it is does not start itself with a word of the dictionary.

```py
def list_of_linked_list(ll):
  result = []
  while len(ll) == 2:
    head, ll = ll
    result.append(head)
  result.reverse()
  return result

def match_word(word, string, pos):
  if len(word) + pos > len(string) or string[pos:pos+len(word)] != word:
    return
  return pos+len(word)

class Dictionary:
  def __init__(self, words):
    self.words = words
  def find(self, string):
    boundary = [(0, ())]
    while len(boundary) != 0:
      pos, matches = boundary.pop()
      has_next = False
      for word in self.words:
        if end := match_word(word, string, pos):
          boundary.append((end, ((end, word), matches)))
          has_next = True
      if not has_next:
        yield list_of_linked_list(matches)

def word_break(word, words):
  dictionary = Dictionary(words)
  for solution in dictionary.find(words):
    i = 0
    for (end, w) in solution:
      print(w, end=" ")
      i = end
    print(word[i:])
```

So:

```
>>> word_break("Wordbreakproblem", d := ["self", "th", "is", "famous", "Word", "break", "b", "r", "e", "a", "k", "br", "bre", "brea", "ak", "problem"])
Word brea k problem 
Word bre ak problem 
Word bre a k problem 
Word br e ak problem 
Word br e a k problem 
Word b r e ak problem 
Word b r e a k problem 
Word break problem
>>> word_break("sWordbreakproblem", d)
sWordbreakproblem
>>> word_break("Wordbreakproblems", d)
Word brea k problem s
Word bre ak problem s
Word bre a k problem s
Word br e ak problem s
Word br e a k problem s
Word b r e ak problem s
Word b r e a k problem s
Word break problem s
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution provided. I understood the method suggested. But unfortunately the word in the question described was mistaken. Apologizing for that. The word is Wordbreakproblems or sWordbreakproblem or Wordbreakproblem. Can you upvote the question too

Comment: @imhans4305 the solution should work with any word. It does work for all the examples you've given.

Comment: I am getting only one pattern. :(

Comment: Ah ok sorry I missunderstood your question. Your really want all possible outputs? Then only the bruteforce way works I fear. I'll give the code for that soon :D

Comment: I dont want all the splits. I am looking for solutions which match with that in list and not matching also

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your approach. Let's consider the word 'abcde'. In your loop, you will check if 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde' are in the dictionary. If there are no words starting with 'a' in your dictionary, then nothing happens in your loop.

You will have to change/modify your approach. For example you could try to call your loop again from the second character onwards if no matches are found in the initial loop and so on.

Comment: Thankyou. Also modified the question. Can you upvote the question ?